# align columns right

Tags: bash, command-line, text

For the command shell, is there a common program like `column` that has an option to align specific or all columns to the right, if not also detect numeric fields and do so automatically for those?

Otherwise what might be the most concise way with text-processing commands?

Example space-delimited input already piped through `| column -t`:

```
TVN         20120419  10.08  10.08  9.15   9.6    1630000  9.17    20120419  4.6      83.88   7376600    -0.21858
INTEGERPL   20120419  143.1  148.9  140.3  142.5  2910     138.53  20120405  4.32503  5.55    1642500    1.26158
JSW         20120419  93.55  94.4   91.25  92.7   116000   90.07   20120329  3.86997  8.54    13155770   1.29315
KERNEL      20120419  73.7   74.9   72.9   74.1   56200    71.8    20120404  3.48432  10.71   2819790    1.50892
EUROCASH    20120419  39.49  41.99  39.01  40.73  812000   38.05   20120328  4.85095  20.21   5280548    2.46091
PEKAO       20120419  145.9  147.8  144.0  145.5  292000   140.2   20120404  3.70615  5.48    68858748   2.63889
PKNORLEN    20120419  38.0   38.5   37.25  37.35  1230000  36.26   20120329  4.15476  21.21   104607200  2.65772
```

Notice readability issues esp. where differences between records are by several magnitudes (like 2nd last column). 
Incidentally, formatting prices to always show N decimal places is a problem of its own. But I've used awk's `OFMT="%.4f"` for that.

Comment: Looking at it again, maybe `rev`ing lines or certain fields, `column`ing, then un`rev`ing them back somehow might do it?  But then it might just be simpler to _sprintf_ away in `awk`, but is already confusing enough to me.

Comment: Ubuntu uses the `column` implementation from `bsdmainutils`. There are other implementations, for instance the `column` implementation from [`util-linux`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/) which has a `-R` option to right-align selected columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alignment and numeric field detection can be achieved by the following simple `awk` program.

```
{
    width=10;
    separator="|";

    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if (match($i, /[-+]*[0-9]+[\.]*[0-9]*/)) {
            printf("%"width"s", $i);
        }
        else { 
            printf("%-"width"s", $i);
        }
        if (i == NF) printf("\n");
        else printf("%s", separator);
    }
}
```

Save it as `column.awk`.

To test how it works try the following:

`echo "abc -1.2 def 2 3 hij" | awk -f column.awk`

The output is:

```
abc       |      -1.2|def       |         2|         3|hij
```

There are 2 tunable parameters inside the `.awk` script:

- *width:* the default field with (used for alignment)
- *separator:* used to separate output columns

Comment: Thanks, I could use that, even though I was hoping to avoid a whole separate script where I usually just resort to Ruby by then :)  Only in my copy I'll add a shebang line of `#!/usr/bin/awk` and `chmod +x` it

Comment: It doesn't auto-find the minimal width for each column. But then I see you mentioned that by using a fixed width. This is good code than can be expanded on.  The alignment problem probably ranks as among the oldest classic challenges in Unix history so I should be able to find various approaches ready to go.

Comment: You're right, this is just a prototype to expand on (or just a proof-of-concept). Determining the column width without any precursory information could be tricky (worst case scenario would be to read in the whole file before outputting anything, which contradicts the line-filtering philosophy). Your `#!` solution is great, to be honest, my script was originally „developed” as a one-liner...

Comment: bash printf is an alternative

Answer (score 0):

[awk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/awk.1posix.html)'s [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html) should be able to do this. For details, you should provide more information about the input and (desired) output format.

Comment: Thanks, I added a sample, any suggestions how to handle generic input? (not knowing the field layout in advance)